# Поделитесь рецептом Deploy на netbeans

Tags: netbeans, развертывание

Поделитесь рецептом Deploy на netbeans или другого мне приходится выполнять 3 операции фиксация, отправка на git и на сервере pull  можно ли как то этот процесс укорить, в netbeans для фиксации задал горячие клавиши, для пуша тоже есть сочетание можно ли их как то объединить?

Comment: Можешь для командной строки скрипт сделать

Comment: А на какой сервер вы развертываете? И что именно? war? ear?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman что есть war ear? Сервер linux Debian Nginx+php-fpm Git pull я как нито осилю мнеб 2 команды фиксации и пуша объединить и не тыкать далее-далее-далее, либо кнопку нажал оно отправилось само в мастер ветку безо всяких подтверждений

Comment: Тоже netbeans. Из командной строки последовательно четыре  команды (можно в один батник прописать) `cd path\to\project` `git add .` `git commit -a -m comment` `git push repository` А deploy - это обычно развёртывание (установка) готового приложения, туда где оно должно работать

Comment: @Sergey ну так средствами нетбинса нельзя на кнопку повесить все это? Если батники использовать, то проще git toolbar, но опятьже надо мышкой тыкать, а хотелось сделать так типа тапнул и все само зафиксилось и отправилось в мастерветку

Comment: Не знаю. Мне и так хорошо. Netbean и git могут работать параллельно. Поэтому лучше всё таки использовать git, Мало что ли в этом нетбинсе багов? Ещё пофиксит что-нибудь не то.

Comment: @АнтонВеселов NB в основном используется в java мире и эти сокращения от туда.